How can we paste together some finite long exact sequences (LES's) at the top page 14 of Weibel (in the SES of complexes to infinite LES proof)?
The Snake Lemma starting diagram at the bottom of page 13 in this proof is:

Here is a link to the above diagram.
Now at the top of page 14, it states "The kernel of the left vertical is $H_n(A)$ and its cokernel is $H_{n-1}(A)$. Therefore the Snake Lemma yields the exact sequence
$$
H_n(A) \xrightarrow{f} H_n(B) \xrightarrow{g} H_n(C) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n-1}(A)\to H_{n-1}(B) \to H_{n-1}(C)
$$
The long exact sequence 1.3.1 is obtained by pasting these sequences together."
What is this pasting operation and how can we guarantee that the infinite long exact sequence is indeed exact at each object?

I think it's because the overlap of each of the consecutive finite LES's is at least 2. If it were just 1 object overlap, then you'd have to prove exactness as the endpoints, but because the overlap is at least two, exactness is already proven at all objects in the final infinite LES.  Do I have this right?

It's a good question of gluing exact sequences... and, I think you're exactly right. :)  Maybe make it an answer...

If you want to paste
$$H_{n+1}(A) \stackrel f{\longrightarrow} H_{n+1}(B)\stackrel g{\longrightarrow}H_{n+1}(C)\stackrel {\partial}{\longrightarrow}\color{blue}{H_{n}(A)\longrightarrow H_{n}(B) \longrightarrow H_{n}(C)}$$
and
$$\color{blue}{H_{n}(A) \stackrel f{\longrightarrow} H_{n}(B)\stackrel g{\longrightarrow}H_n(C)}\stackrel {\partial}{\longrightarrow}H_{n-1}(A)\longrightarrow H_{n-1}(B) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(C)$$
Notice that there are three terms in common, so there aren't really any ''new'' points to check exactness at.
Hope this helps. :>

I like your use of colors here :)
